# How to iterate object in loop C#?

Tags: c#

I initialized an object:

```
object[,] A = new object[range.RowCount() + 1, range.ColumnCount() + 1];
```

After filling this I need to iterate all elements of object in loop.
How to iterate this in `for loop`?

I tried to do: `for(var i = 0; i < A.Count(); i++){}`

But there is not property `Count()` for object, also this is matrix.

Comment: `Length` is the property for arrays.  You can also use it in a `foreach`.  Or nested `for` loops using `GetLength` if you need to keep track of the current row and column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For things like this you might want *nested loops*, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < A.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        //do your magic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have `Length` property:

```
for (var i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
{
    var b = A[i, 1];
}
```

`Count()` is a method of IEnumerable